# Cubic spline method for longitudinal series data?

Tags: r, regression, spline, mixed-models, bspline

I have a serial data formatted as follows:

```
time    milk    Animal_ID
30      25.6    1
31      27.2    1
32      24.4    1
33      17.4    1
34      33.6    1
35      25.4    1
33      29.4    2
34      25.4    2
35      24.7    2
36      27.4    2
37      22.4    2
80      24.6    3
81      24.5    3
82      23.5    3
83      25.5    3
84      24.4    3
85      23.4    3
.   .   .
```

Generally, 300 animals have records of milk in different time points of short period. However, if we join their data together and do not care about different animal_ID, we would have a curve between milk~time like this, the line in figure below:
[image]
Also, in the above figure, we have data for 1 example animal, they are short and highly variable. My purposed is to smooth each animal data but it would be would if the model allows learning general patter from whole data to be included. I used different smooth model (ns, bs, smooth.spline) with the following format but it just did not work:

```
mod <- lme(milk ~ bs(time, df=3), data=dat, random = ~1|Animal_ID)
```

I am hoping if somebody has already dealt with this problem would give me an advice. Thanks
The full dataset can be accessed from here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/z9b5teh3su87uu7/dat.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you use `mgcv` package. This is one of the recommended R packages, performing a class of models called **generalized additive mixed models**. You can simply load it by `library(mgcv)`. This is a very powerful library, which can handle from the simplest linear regression model, to generalized linear models, to additive models, to generalized additive models, as well as models with mixed effects (fixed effects + random effects). You can list all (exported) functions of `mgcv` via

```
ls("package:mgcv")
```

And you can see there are many of them.

For your specific data and problem, you may use a model with formula:

```
model <- milk ~ s(time, bs = 'cr', k = 100) + s(Animal_ID, bs = 're')
```

In `mgcv`, `s()` is a setup for smooth functions, represented by spline basis implied by `bs`. "cr" is the cubic spline basis, which is exactly what you want. `k` is the number of knots. It should be chosen depending on the number of unique values of variable `time` in your data set. If you set `k` to exactly this number, you end up with a smoothing spline; while any value smaller than that means a regression spline. However, both will be penalized (if you know what penalization mean). I read your data in:

```
dat <- na.omit(read.csv("data.txt", header = TRUE))  ## I saved you data into file "data.txt"
dat$Animal_ID <- factor(dat$Animal_ID)
nrow(dat)  ## 12624 observations
length(unique(dat$time))  ## 157 unique time points
length(ID <- levels(dat$Animal_ID))  ## 355 cows
```

There are 157 unique values, so I reckon `k = 100` is possibly appropriate.

For `Animal_ID` (coerced as a factor), we need a model term for random effect. "re" is a special class for i.i.d random effect. It is passed to `bs` for some internal matrix construction reason (so this is not a smooth function!).

Now to fit a GAM model, you can call the legacy `gam` or the constantly developing `bam` (gam for big data). I think you will use the latter. They have the same calling convention similar to `lm` and `glm`. For example, you can do:

```
fit <- bam(model, data = dat, family = "gaussian", discrete = TRUE, nthreads = 2)
```

As you can see, `bam` allows multi-core parallel computation via `nthreads`. While `discrete` is a newly developed feature which can speed up matrix formation.

Since you are dealing with time series data, finally you might consider some temporal autocorrelation. `mgcv` allows configuration of AR1 correlation, whose correlation coefficient is passed by `bam` argument `rho`. However, you need an extra index `AR_start` to tell `mgcv` how the time series breaks up into pieces. For example, when reaching a different `Animal_ID`, `AR_start` get a `TRUE` to indicate a new segment of time series. See `?bam` for details.

`mgcv` also provides

1. `summary.gam` function for model summary
2. `gam.check` for basic model checking
3. `plot.gam` function for plotting individual terms
4. `predict.gam` (or `predict.bam`) for prediction on new data.

For example, the summary of the above suggested model is:

```
> summary(fit)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
milk ~ s(time, bs = "cr", k = 100) + s(Animal_ID, bs = "re")

Parametric coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  26.1950     0.2704   96.89   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                edf Ref.df       F  p-value    
s(time)       10.81  13.67   5.908 1.99e-11 ***
s(Animal_ID) 351.43 354.00 136.449  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.805   Deviance explained = 81.1%
fREML =  29643  Scale est. = 5.5681    n = 12624
```

The `edf` (effective degree of freedom) may be thought of as a measure of the degree of non-linearity. So we put in `k = 100`, while ending up with `edf = 10.81`. **This suggest that the spline `s(time)` has been heavily penalized.** You can view the what `s(time)` looks like by:

```
plot.gam(fit, page = 1)
```

Note that the random effect `s(Animal_ID)` also has a "smooth", that is an cow-specific constant. For random effects, a Gaussian QQ plot will be returned.

The diagnostic figures returned by

```
invisible(gam.check(fit))
```

looks OK, so I think the model is acceptable (I am not offering you model selection, so think up a better model if you think there is).

If you want to make prediction for `Animal_ID = 26`, you may do

```
newd <- data.frame(time = 1:150, Animal_ID = 26)
oo <- predict.gam(fit, newd, type = `link`, se.fit = TRUE)
```

Note that

- You need to include both variables in `newd` (otherwise `mgcv` complains missing variable)
- since you have only one spline smooth `s(time)`, and the random effect term `s(Animal_ID)` is a constant per `Animal_ID`. so it is OK to use `type = 'link'` for individual prediction. By the way, `type = 'terms'` is slower than `type = 'link'`.

If you want to make prediction for more than one cows, try something like this:

```
pred.ID <- ID[1:10]  ## predict first 10 cows
newd <- data.frame (time = rep (1:150, times = n), Animal_ID = factor (rep (pred.ID, each = 150)))
oo <- predict.bam (fit, newd, type = "link", se.fit = TRUE)
```

Note that

- I have used `predict.bam` here, as now we have `150 * 10 = 1500` data points to predict. Plus: we require `se.fit = TRUE`. This is rather expensive, so use `predict.bam` is faster than `predict.gam`. Particularly, if you have fitted your model using `bam(..., discrete = TRUE)`, you can have `predict.bam(..., discrete = TRUE)`. Prediction process goes through the same matrix formation steps as in model fitting (see `?smoothCon` used in model fitting and `?PredictMat` used in prediction, if you are keen to know more internal structure of `mgcv`.)
- I specified `Animal_ID` as factors, because this is a random effect.

For more on `mgcv`, you can refer to library manual. Check specially `?mgcv`, `?gam`, `?bam` `?s`.

---

**Final update**

Though I said that I will not help you with model section, but I think this model is better (it gives higher `adj-Rsquared`) and is also more reasonable in sense:

```
model <- milk ~ s(time, bs = 'cr', k = 20) + s(Animal_ID, bs = 're') + s(Animal_ID, time, bs = 're')
```

The last term is imposing a **random slop**. This implies that we are assuming that **each individual cow has different growing/reducing pattern of milk production**. This is a **more sensible assumption** in your problem. The earlier model with only random intercept is not sufficient. After adding this random slop, the smooth term `s(time)` looks smoother. This is a good sign not a bad sign, because we want some simple explanation for `s(time)`, don't we? Compare the `s(time)` you get from both models, and see what you discover.

I have also reduced `k = 100` to `k = 20`. As we saw in previous fit, the `edf` for this term is about 10, so `k = 20` is pretty sufficient.

Comment: @Zheyyuan: thanks for your suggestion, I applied mgcv model and made a short plot between milk and time for whole data and it seems good. However, I have been able to make prediction of milk for each Animal. 
I used this but did not work:
'newd <- data.frame(time=c(1,150))'
'pred <- predict.gam(fit,newd,type="terms",se=TRUE)'

Comment: I tried your latter comments. Worked perfectly as my expectation. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Zheyyuan: when I check for plots between smoothed and actual data. It seems that the model just did somethign very linear, which is not good for some case. Does the term "cubic" work really in this case? Please see the whole plots here, page 39 for an example of not good fit. https://www.dropbox.com/s/vmv96mvlj38t8e3/BWgaussian.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Yes, agree with you about k. No significant improvement when specifying k of 100 compared to 10.