# Multivariate regression splines in R

Tags: r, regression, lm, spline

Most people are probably familiar with `bs` from splines:

```
library(splines)

workingModel <- lm(mpg ~ factor(gear) + bs(wt, knots = 5) + hp, data = mtcars)

bs(mtcars$wt, knots = 4)
```

This uses a b-spline for the singe variable weight, but you can also do multivariate splines:

```
bs(cbind(mtcars$wt,mtcars$hp), knots = 4)
```

But this produces a matrix with twice as many rows as `mtcars`, so when I try:

```
brokenModel <- lm(mpg ~ bs(cbind(mtcars$wt,mtcars$hp), knots = 4), data = mtcars)
```

I get an error about differing lengths.

My question is: how do I use the multivariate spline in a model if it has a different number of rows than my outcome variable? Do I stack my outcome variable on top of itself `y <- c(y, y)`? Why does the multivariate spline produce extra rows?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Carl, you can use y~X-1, where X is your bs(...), also see: http://people.stat.sfu.ca/~cschwarz/Consulting/Trinity/Phase2/TrinityWorkshop/Workshop-handouts/TW-04-Intro-splines.pdf

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't use `splines::bs` in this case, as it is strictly for construction of a univariate spline. If you do `bs(mat)` where `mat` is a matrix, it is just doing `bs(c(mat))`. For example,

```
mat <- matrix(runif(8), 4, 2)
identical(bs(mat), bs(c(mat)))
# [1] TRUE
```

This explains why you get double number of rows, when doing `bs(cbind(mtcars$wt,mtcars$hp)`.

---

To create a 2D spline, the simplest way is to create additive spline:

```
lm(mpg ~ factor(gear) + bs(wt, knots = 5) + bs(hp, knots = 4), mtcars)
```

but this may not be what you want. Then consider interaction:

```
model <- lm(mpg ~ factor(gear) + bs(wt, knots = 5):bs(hp, knots = 4), mtcars)
```

The `bs(wt, knots = 5):bs(hp, knots = 4)` is forming row-wise Kronecker product between the two design matrices. Since `bs(wt, knots = 5)` is a matrix of 4 columns, and `bs(hp, knots = 4)` is a matrix of 3 columns, the interaction has 4 * 3 = 12 columns.

---

Alternatively, consider using `mgcv` package. In `mgcv`, multivariate splines can be constructed in two ways:

- isotropic thin-plate splines;
- scale invariant tensor product splines.

Clearly you want the second here, as `wt` and `hp` have different units. To construct tensor product splines, we can use:

```
library(mgcv)
fit <- gam(mpg ~ factor(gear)
                 + s(wt, bs = 'cr', k = 4, fx = TRUE)
                 + s(hp, bs = 'cr', k = 4, fx = TRUE)
                 + ti(wt, hp, bs = 'cr', k = c(4, 4), d = c(1, 1), fx = TRUE),
                 data = mtcars)
```

Here, I specially set `fx = TRUE` to disable penalized regression.

I don't want to write an extensive answer to introduce `mgcv`. For how `s`, `ti` and `gam` work, just read documentation. If you need to bridge the gap in theory, grab Simon Wood's book published in 2006: *Generalized Additive Models: an introduction with R*.

---

> A practical example of `mgcv` usage?

I had an answer [Cubic spline method for longitudinal series data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37040552/4891738) which might help you get familiar with `mgcv`. But as an introductory example, it only shows how to work with univariate spline. Fortunately, that is also the key. Tensor product spline is constructed from univariate spline.

My other answers related to `mgcv` is more of theoretical aspect; while not all my answers related to `spline` is making reference to `mgcv`. So that question & answer is the best I could give you at this stage.

> Would the scale invariant tensor product splines be equivalent to radial smoothing or would that be the isotropic thin-place splines?

Radial smoothing is equivalent to thin-plate spline, as the basis function for a thin-plate spline is radial. That is why it is isotropic and can be used in spatial regression.

Tensor product spline is scale invariant, as it is constructed as (pairwise) multiplication of univariate spline basis.